# IViewLocalizer internally string.Format and no params are passed into custom IStringLocalizer

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, localization

Imagine this string: `Welcome, {0}. Your age is {1}`. If someone were to do `@Localizer["welcome", "Timmy"]` the page would fail to render, because it expects 2 arguments instead of 1.

My custom implementation that inherits from `IStringLocalizer`, has the following code:

```
public LocalizedString this[string name] => this[name, new object[0]];

public LocalizedString this[string name, params object[] arguments] 
{
    get
    {
        var translation = _translations[name];

        if(arguments.Any()) 
        {
            var formatted = string.Format(translation, arguments); 

            return new LocalizedString(name, formatted, false);
        }

        return new LocalizedString(name, translation, false);
    }
}
```

This works perfectly, except for one thing: `arguments` is always empty. There are no arguments, even though I know the method gets hit (breakpoint will get hit).

Because of that, I cannot combat the internally called `string.Format`, which throws an exception if there are fewer arguments than expected (in this case only 1 argument).

I would like to expand my code to `try/catch` the `string.Format` in my code, so I can log potential fails, and then fallback to showing the key instead, or simply replace missing arguments with `## MISING ARGUMENT ##` or something like that.

How am I supposed to combat this? It's weird that the method gets hit, but that there are no arguments.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code gets hit but without parameters is the index from this class:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization::HtmlLocalizer

```
    public virtual LocalizedHtmlString this[string name, params object[] arguments]
    {
        get
        {
            if (name == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(name));
            }

            return ToHtmlString(_localizer[name], arguments);
        }
    }
```

as you can see it doesn't call _localizer[name, arguments] but _localizer[name].

The logic seems to be that ToHtmlString creates and returns an instance of LocalizedHtmlString and the Value has the following description

```
    /// <summary>
    /// The original resource string, prior to formatting with any constructor arguments.
    /// </summary>
    public string Value { get; }
```

looks like you are not supposed to format it but let the method LocalizedHtmlString.WriteTo do the formatting.

Answer (score 0):

I had my own implementations of `IStringLocalizer<TResourceSource>` and `IHtmlLocalizer<TResourceSource>` as well.  I'm not sure what your behavior was, but for me, when page was rendering and `LocalizedHtmlString.WriteTo` failed with parameter count mismatch, it just stopped immediately and whatever was partially rendered displayed and no error happened (to the user's point of view).  However, there was stuff in the Output window which is how I confirmed the `LocalizedHtmlString.WriteTo` problem.

To solve, I basically take the given resource string and find the highest parameter substitution.  Then if the passed in arguments do not contain enough arguments, I append enough parameters with a dummy string the OP suggested indicating missing parameter so the page renders but displays 'missing' in the string.

```
public virtual LocalizedHtmlString this[ string name ] => GetLocalizedString( name, new object[] { }, GetValue, IsResourceFound, GetLocalizedHtmlItem );

public virtual LocalizedHtmlString this[ string name, params object[] arguments ] 
{
    var ls = _localizer[name, arguments];

    if ( !ls.IsResourceNotFound( ls ) )
    {
        var matches = parameterCount.Matches( ls.Value );

        var expectedParameters = matches.Count > 0
            ? matches.Cast<Match>()
                .Max( m => int.Parse( m.Groups[ "number" ].Value ) + 1 )
            : 0;

        if ( arguments.Length < expectedParameters )
        {
            var protectedArgs =
                arguments.Concat(
                    Enumerable
                        .Range( arguments.Length, expectedParameters - arguments.Length )
                        .Select( p => $"{{MISSING PARAM #{p}}}" )
                ).ToArray();

            return _localizer[name, protectedArgs];
        }
    }

    return ls;
}
```